# Is there a variable I can set in the environment which will point vim to my ctags?

Tags: vim, ctags

I know that I can run

```
set tags=${SOMEPATH}/tags
```

And that I can set `${SOMEPATH}`, but is there a default path that vim is looking on when searching for a tags file that I can update without touching the vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `'tags'` is `./tags,tags`, which means Vim will search for a file named `tags` either in the current file's directory, or in the current working directory (`:pwd`).

Modifying the `'tags'` option would be the straightforward approach; this doesn't have to be in the `.vimrc`; you could also do this when launching Vim [`:help --cmd`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--cmd), or in a [`modeline`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline) inside the edited file.

But if for whatever reason this isn't possible, the best way I can think of is to launch Vim in the directory that has the `tags` file, and open all files relative to that (and without `:set autochdir`).

Comment: I use `set tags=.git/tags;~` but the interesting part is the semicolon-tilde